# Geoplot not displaying x,y axis python

Tags: python, seaborn, geopandas, kernel-density, geoplot

I'm trying to use geoplot to draw a heatmap of crime distribution in San Francisco county. The problem is when I used the dataset from geoplot to draw the map of SF, the x,y axes do not appear. I'm using this map for my final presentation, so I figured it would be more readable for my audiences with axes displayed for them(longitude&latitude as axes). I've searched as many documents as I could, and I tried to use ax.axis('on') but didn't work. I would be much appreciate for any advice given. Thanks
(BTW I'm doing this on jupyter)
df is the data frame I used which contained 500k crime records with locations containing longitude & latitude.

```
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
sf = gpd.read_file(gplt.datasets.get_path("san_francisco"))
count = gdf1
ax = gplt.polyplot(sf, projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(),figsize=(10,10))
gplt.kdeplot(count, cmap="Reds", shade=True, clip=sf, ax=ax, cbar=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geoplot is built on top of cartopy, and the returned axis objects do seem to be normal cartopy `GeoAxis` objects, so you should be able to use any figure customizations available within that library. By default cartopy plots do not include axis ticks/ticklabels because the library is frequently used to plot in a projection, where the x and y values do not correspond to lat/lon.

To add gridlines in cartopy, use [`ax.gridlines`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines). These will correctly handle your projection and draw lat/lon lines as contours on your map.

From the docs on [adding map gridlines and tick labels](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/gridliner.html#cartopy-map-gridlines-and-tick-labels):

```py
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, dms=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
```

There are a ton of arguments to gridlines and ways to customize them but hopefully that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach where more geometry is available is a mapbox density plot.  Additional layers can be added if a grid is required.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.json_normalize(
    requests.get("https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wg3w-h783.json").json()
)

px.density_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="latitude",
    lon="longitude",
    radius=10,
    color_continuous_scale="reds",
    center=dict(
        lat=df["latitude"].astype(float).mean(),
        lon=df["longitude"].astype(float).mean(),
    ),
    zoom=10,
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
).update_layout(margin={"t":0,"b":0,"l":300,"r":300})
```

[image]